# Where to look for database samples/schema?

Tags: sql, database

I found http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/ very useful. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MedicineMan - Have u gone nuts? Ya i have time travelled to post this question after I saw your latest post

Comment: ah whoops. Have been using SO less and less recently.  I think there's room for both posts, I don't know why that guy was voting to delete mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for data models, I recommend the following books:

- [The Data Model Resource Book, Vol.
  1: A Library of Universal Data
  Models for All Enterprises](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471380237)
- [The Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 2: A Library of Data Models for Specific Industries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471353485)
- [The Data Model Resource Book: Universal Patterns for Data Modeling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470178450)

I have Vol 1 and Vol 2 and these have been pretty helpful in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have db samples in **VS2005** and **VS2008**, but you can also download it from here:
[Northwind Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227484.aspx)